# ng-template inside ng-content Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use template which will be passed used as ng-content in the component selector HTML file.

```html
<day-summary
  [data]="summary"
  *ngIf="(events.length)>=5;then busy;else notSoBusy"
  >You have <b>{{events.length}}</b> tasks to complete.</day-summary
>
<ng-template #busy>
  You seems busy today. You have <b>{{events.length}}</b> tasks to complete.
</ng-template>
<ng-template #notSoBusy>
  It seems like you have lot of free time. You have
  <b>{{events.length}}</b> tasks to complete.
</ng-template>
```

I would like to show it as busy or not busy. It's working as busy or not busy but the 'day-summary' component.html template is not working.
How am I supposed to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `ng-contiainer` as demonstrated below:

```html
<day-summary [data]="summary">
  <ng-container *ngIf="events.length >= 5; then busy; else notSoBusy"></ng-container>
</day-summary>

<ng-template #busy>
  You seems busy today. You have <b>{{events.length}}</b> tasks to complete.
</ng-template>
<ng-template #notSoBusy>
  It seems like you have lot of free time. You have <b>{{events.length}}</b> tasks to complete.
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
<day-summary [data]=summary>
      You have <b>{{events.length}}</b> tasks to complete.
</day-summary>
<ng-container *ngIf="events.length >= 5">
      You seems busy today. You have <b>{{events.length}}</b> tasks to complete.
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="events.length < 5">
      It seems like you have lot of free time. You have <b>{{events.length}}</b> 
      tasks to complete.
</ng-container>
...
```

Put both containers at the positio nwhere yo uwant to diplay it conditionally. besides ng-container you can use any html element instead to fit into your layout.